# Copy file to system on android kitkat error

Tags: java, android, file, permissions, android-4.4-kitkat

I've been using this method to have su permissions, run echo commands and copy files on android 4.1.2 but since I switched to kitkat it doesn't work anymore.

When I run my app it shows the su prompt and I can set the su permissions with no problems.
I have problems when I wanna apply an echo value to a system file or when I wanna copy an asset from the app to the system.

Here the code:

```
 // SU
public static String SU_wop(String cmds) {
    String out = null;
    try {
        out = new String();
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(cmds+"\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        p.waitFor();
        InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        while (true) {
            read = stdout.read(buffer);
            out += new String(buffer, 0, read);
            if (read < 4096) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        final Activity activity = new Main();
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Error Occured...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        Log.e("cocoremanager", "Error executing SU command, flag:0x2");
    }
    return out.substring(0,out.length()-1);
}

//Copy files
public static void copyAssets(String script,String path,int mode,Context context) {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(script);
        File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), script);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e("cocoremanager", "Failed to handle: " + script, e);
    }
    mRunAsSU("mkdir -p " + path, "cp -f "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+script+" "+path+"/"+script, "rm "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+script, "chmod "+Integer.toString(mode)+" "+path+"/"+script);
}

 public static void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}

 public static void mRunAsSU(String... cmds) {
    Process process;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        for(int i=0;i<cmds.length;i++)
            os.writeBytes(cmds[i]+"\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("cocoretest", "Error executing....");
    }
}
}

 class SU extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... cmds) {
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        for(int i=0;i<cmds.length;i++)
            os.writeBytes(cmds[i]+"\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: I have no errors,it allows the su permissions.. just it doesn't copy any assert file from app to etc/inid. folder. This method was working at 100% on jb. Now i don't know why it is not working.

Comment: Are you testing on the emulator or a real device?

Comment: Real device and logcats are just saing me that the app allows the su perms, not errors. I really don't understand

Comment: I have no clue my friend, I found that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226053/file-copy-and-replacing-in-system-directory-with-root-permission it may help you!

Comment: Perhaps your system partition is read only either due to mount flags or hardware locking.  Hacks like this are inevitably non-portable and should not be attempted if you are not in a position to meaningfully debug them.

Comment: Nope, I use a method to mount system in rw mode and it works. So I think it is only a permissions problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is SELinux which was introduced with Android 4.3. See: http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/enhancements43.html

I think there is no easy way to bypass SELinux. Even popular Apps requiring root have big problems since 4.3

Comment: In my device SELinux is disabled